# WFS Request Layer (GML) with Filter

Tags: gis, geoserver

Is there a solution to request the GML layer from Geoserver with filter like using `bbox`:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/tiger/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&
request=GetFeature&typeName=tiger:poi&maxFeatures=50&
bbox=-74.0104611,40.70758763,-74.00153046439813,40.719885123828675
```

The result will be specific filtering the bounding box (lat/lon), based on `bbox` parameter that user entered.

**The Result:**

```
<wfs:FeatureCollection xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.census.gov http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/tiger/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&typeName=tiger%3Apoi http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/schemas/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-basic.xsd">
    <gml:boundedBy>
        <gml:null>unknown</gml:null>
    </gml:boundedBy>
    <gml:featureMember>
        <tiger:poi fid="poi.4">
            <tiger:the_geom>
                <gml:Point srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326"><gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">-74.00857344,40.71194565</gml:coordinates></gml:Point>
            </tiger:the_geom>
            <tiger:NAME>lox</tiger:NAME>
            <tiger:THUMBNAIL>pics/22037884-Ti.jpg</tiger:THUMBNAIL>
            <tiger:MAINPAGE>pics/22037884-L.jpg</tiger:MAINPAGE>
         </tiger:poi></gml:featureMember>
</wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

**The problem now, I want to filter the data based on the `<tiger:NAME>lox</tiger:NAME>`, already tried with entered the `tiger:NAME=lox` as a parameter when request, the result just same like when enter no parameter. Is there a solution for this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Filter Encoding with Spatial Filter within WFS-Request](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/Filter-Encoding-with-Spatial-Filter-within-WFS-Request-td4230814.html) and [Geoserver Filter](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-reference/filters.html). I found that there is a parameter named `filter` and the value can enter like this:

`http://localhost:8080/geoserver/tiger/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=tiger:poi&maxFeatures=2&filter=<PropertyIsEqualTo><PropertyName>NAME</PropertyName><Literal>lox</Literal></PropertyIsEqualTo>`